# Reference request for Kummer-Artin-Schreier-Witt theory

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, group-schemes, kummer-theory

I cannot find the following 4 papers by *Sekiguchi–Suwa* in their works on *Kummer–Artin–Schreier–Witt theory*:

1. *On the unified Kummer–Artin–Schreier–Witt theory*, Prépublications du laboratoire de Mathématiques Pures de Bordeaux, Prépublication nº 111 (1999).
2. *On the unified Kummer–Artin–Schreier–Witt sequences*
3. *Théories de Kummer–Artin–Schreier–Witt*,  C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris 319 (1994), 105-110.
4. *Theorie de Kummer–Artin–Schreier*, C. R. Acad.
   Sci. Paris 312 (1991), 417-420.

I will be very happy if someone can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Is [this](https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/0803-13.pdf)  the reference (2) you are looking for?

Comment: Also, the Comptes Rendus can be found here: [link](https://www.academie-sciences.fr/en/Transmettre-les-connaissances/comptes-rendus-de-l-academie-des-sciences-numerisees-sur-le-site-de-la-bibliotheque-nationale-de-france.html). If I understood it right, references (3) and (4) are the following: [3](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k57326058/f109.item) and [4](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k54707877/f423.item)

Comment: @Emily Thank you very much. Exactly 2,3 and 4 are what you kindly shared, Unfortunately, 2 is in Japanese! I thought it is English. But, the most comprehensive reference is 1, as I saw on Sekiguchi's page it is a 90-page paper.

Comment: My pleasure! I tried to look for 1 too, but ultimately failed :/. Maybe you could try emailing Sekiguchi or Suwa (I think this email might work for Sekiguchi: `sekiguti@math.chuo-u.ac.jp` and it seems you can contact Suwa using [this link](https://jglobal.jst.go.jp/en/detail?JGLOBAL_ID=200901088756064510))

Comment: Thank you again. This is a good suggestion. I'll try for it.

Comment: @Ehsan Shahoseini I have a scanned copy of the paper (1) which I've put [here](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/matthieu.romagny/docs/Sekiguchi_Suwa_On_the_unified_Kummer_Artin_Schreier_Witt_theory_preprint_Bordeaux.pdf). Let me know if you have trouble finding the other references.

Comment: @matthieu Romagny Thanks a lot. It's great. Also, Emily kindly help me for other 3 ones. And you kindly help for main reference of this theory. Thanks to both of you.